# RXJs unsubscription issue in chat application

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a chat application written in Angular 9.
In my service i have:

```
    public chatGetMessages = () => {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        console.log("API GOT ITEM")
        this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
            console.log("on apiservice", message)
            observer.next({type:"new-message",message:message});
        });
    });
```

I have a component running on a dialog with:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.subscription= this.apiService
       .chatGetMessages()
       .subscribe((message: any) => {
        if (message.type == "new-message") 
            this.messageList.push({ message: message.message.message, from: message.message.from, dt: message.message.dt });

  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

The first time it runs fine, if i close and reopen the dialog, i got 2 messages, the third time i got 3 messages and so on, as if the subscription was not unsubscribed.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: We'll need to see a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure that the dialog is being destroyed?